# multiplication tables - pyhton

Tags: python

multiplication tables - python

expected result : explanation about global/ local

```
num_front = 1
num_second = 1

while num_front <= 9:

    while num_second <= 9:
        multi = num_front * num_second   
        print(f"{num_front} * {num_second} = {multi}")
        num_second += 1
    num_front += 1
```

> > result : 1 * 1 = 1 ~ 1 * 9 = 9

```
num_front = 1

while num_front <= 9:
    num_second = 1
    while num_second <= 9:
        multi = num_front * num_second   
        print(f"{num_front} * {num_second} = {multi}")
        num_second += 1
    num_front += 1
```

> > result : 1 * 1 = 1 ~ 9 * 9 = 81

only difference is that 'num_second = 1' is located in local for the second one.
Could you explain why the first method doesn't work properly?
Thank you.

Comment: For that I recommend running a debugger. You can follow what `num_front` and `num_second` are each time you loop. (Hint: when is num_second reset ?)

Comment: how could the result be `1 * 1 = 1 ~ 9 * 9 = 81`?  you are not printing the `~` symbol anywhere

Comment: Try using a nested for loop. Also, in the context of the code you've shown, all your variables are in global address space

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating num_second in the correct spot. In the first solution you gave, you made num_second a local variable and this makes it so it only resets to 1 that very first time. So, as you are going through the first while loop it makes the first check that num_front is <=9 and in this case it is, so it goes to the second while loop and increments by one until it reaches 9 and that loop stops.

Then, num_front will increment by 1 go through the first loop again but then it won't go to the second loop because num_second is already at 9 so it will just keep incrementing num_front until it reaches 9 then the whole program will stop.

In the second answer the difference is that num_second gets reset back to 1 each time it completes that second loop. This allows the first loop to also reach 9 and be able to go into the second loop each time.

My suggestion when doing something like this is to write down on a paper what each value increments to at each iteration to help you understand how the loop works.

For example:

| num_front | num_second | multi |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 | 6 |
| 1 | 7 | 7 |
| 1 | 8 | 8 |
| 1 | 9 | 9 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

And so on...

Answer (score -1):

The num second is global in the first case, meaning it is not reset after the end of the second `for()`loop. In the first case, after the end of the second loop, num second isn't reset to 1, so it just stops after the iteration.

In the second case, `num_second`is local to the loop, meaning that after every second loop, when your code goes back to your first loop, it will reset your number to 1. So the second loop is iterated while the first one satisfies the condition you added to it.

In general, if you want your second loop to be executed each time your first loop goes through an element, always reset your variables at the beginning or end (whether they're local or global). The local usage of a variable is there to help, but isn't the exclusive solution to your problem.

Here's another example of code that works where my `second_num` is still global.

```
num_front = 1
num_second = 1
while num_front <= 9:
    
    while num_second <= 9:
        multi = num_front * num_second   
        print(f"{num_front} * {num_second} = {multi}")
        num_second += 1
    num_front+=1
    num_second = 1
```

Comment: In my code yes, but clearly not in his second which seems to be the one working. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999881/in-c-are-variables-declared-within-a-loop-local)

Comment: Why is looking at some C code relevant?

Comment: It explains the difference between local and global variables. You seem confused about the topic.

Comment: It explains the difference between local and global variables in C.